# "kubectl get nodes" shows NotReady always even after giving the appropriate IP

Tags: kubernetes, kubelet

i am trying to setup a kubernetes cluster for testing purpose with a master and one minion. When i run the kubectl get nodes it always says NotReady. Following the configuration on minion  in /etc/kubernetes/kubelet

```
KUBELET_ADDRESS="--address=0.0.0.0"
KUBELET_PORT="--port=10250"
KUBELET_HOSTNAME="--hostname-override=centos-minion"
KUBELET_API_SERVER="--api-servers=http://centos-master:8080"
KUBELET_ARGS=""
```

When kubelete service is started following logs could be seen

> Mar 16 13:29:49 centos-minion kubelet: E0316 13:29:49.126595   53912 event.go:202] Unable to write event: 'Post http://centos-master:8080/api/v1/namespaces/default/events: dial tcp 10.143.219.12:8080: i/o timeout' (may retry after sleeping)
>
> Mar 16 13:16:01 centos-minion kube-proxy: E0316 13:16:01.195731   53595 event.go:202] Unable to write event: 'Post http://localhost:8080/api/v1/namespaces/default/events: dial tcp [::1]:8080: getsockopt: connection refused' (may retry after sleeping)

Following is the config on master /etc/kubernetes/apiserver

```
KUBE_API_ADDRESS="--bind-address=0.0.0.0"
KUBE_API_PORT="--port=8080"
KUBELET_PORT="--kubelet-port=10250"
KUBE_SERVICE_ADDRESSES="--service-cluster-ip-range=10.254.0.0/16"
```

/etc/kubernetes/config

```
KUBE_ETCD_SERVERS="--etcd-servers=http://centos-master:2379"
KUBE_LOGTOSTDERR="--logtostderr=true"
KUBE_LOG_LEVEL="--v=0"
KUBE_ALLOW_PRIV="--allow-privileged=false"
KUBE_MASTER="--master=http://centos-master:8080"
```

On master following processes are properly running

> kube      5657     1  0 Mar15 ?        00:12:05 /usr/bin/kube-apiserver --logtostderr=true --v=0 --etcd-servers=http://centos-master:2379 --address=0.0.0.0 --port=8080 --kubelet-port=10250 --allow-privileged=false --service-cluster-ip-range=10.254.0.0/16
>
> kube      5690     1  1 Mar15 ?        00:16:01 /usr/bin/kube-controller-manager --logtostderr=true --v=0 --master=http://centos-master:8080
>
> kube      5723     1  0 Mar15 ?        00:02:23 /usr/bin/kube-scheduler --logtostderr=true --v=0 --master=http://centos-master:8080

So i still do not know what is missing.

Comment: Are you able to telnet master on port 8080 ? And what is IP of master ?

Comment: Yes. I am able to ping the master and its reachable. IP of the master is 10.x.x.12 and this is also configured in /etc/hosts

Comment: Try "telnet 10.x.x.12 8080" from minion and share the output.

Comment: Test the api-server from the master itself. It looks like it did not start (or not start correct).

Comment: apiserver seems to be fine
kube      7511     1  0 Mar16 ?        00:07:56 /usr/bin/kube-apiserver --logtostderr=true --v=0 --etcd-servers=http://127.0.0.1:2379 --insecure-bind-address=0.0.0.0 --insecure-port=8080 --kubelet-port=10250 --allow-privileged=false --service-cluster-ip-range=10.254.0.0/16
kube      7545     1  1 Mar16 ?        00:10:17 /usr/bin/kube-controller-manager --logtostderr=true --v=0 --master=http://centos-master:8080
kube      7579     1  0 Mar16 ?        00:01:35 /usr/bin/kube-scheduler --logtostderr=true --v=0 --master=http://centos-master:8080

Comment: @user2486495 Sorry telnet service is currently not available on the node. It would take sometime to install since it needs some firewall related changes for it to connect to internet.

Comment: Do you have a CNI? Also do a kubectl decribe on your node to get more details

Comment: Same problem happened with me while running kubernetes after a long time in AWS. The problem was due to iptables and firewalld blocking the updates sent by minions. I do stop the AWS instances while I am not working on it. So each time I start the AWS EC2 instance, I have to manually stop the iptables to make it work.

Comment: How did you build the cluster? if you use kubeadm  to setup the cluster it will take care of some of the default configuration settings.

Comment: @Prashant, is your problem still unresolved?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue when I setting up the kubernetes with fedora following the steps on kubernetes.io.
In the tutorial, it's commenting out KUBELET_ARGS="--cgroup-driver=systemd" in node's /etc/kubernetes/kubelet, if you uncomment it, you will see the node status become ready.
Hope this help

Comment: I am using Ubuntu and there is no file called /etc/kubernetes/kubelet

Answer (score 0):

**rejoin the worker nodes to the master**.

My install is on three physical machines. One master and two workers.  All needed reboots.

you will need your join token, which you probably don't have:

```
sudo kubeadm token list
```

copy the TOKEN field data, the output looks like this (no, that's not my real one):

TOKEN 
**ow3v08ddddgmgzfkdkdkd7**   18h       2018-07-30T12:39:53-05:00   authentication,signing   The default bootstrap token generated by 'kubeadm init'.   system:bootstrappers:kubeadm:default-node-token

THEN join the cluster here.  Master node IP is the real IP address of your machine:

```
sudo kubeadm join --token <YOUR TOKEN HASH> <MASTER_NODE_IP>:6443 --discovery-token-unsafe-skip-ca-verification
```

Answer (score 0):

Have to restart kubelet service in node (systemctl enable kubelet & systemctl restart kubelet). Then you can see your node is in "Ready" status.